# Пытаюсь сконфигурировать hibernate и настроить работу с базой данных

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, hibernate, configuration

на картинке видно что я указываю поля все делаю по инструкции но ничего не получается(( подскажите пожалуйста что мне сделать или где что настроить.

Спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предоставлять код (что в вопросе, что в ответе) в виде скриншота - очень и очень плохая идея.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменял

```
<class catalog="trade_project" name="com.trade.project.entities.Announcement"
        schema="trade_project" table="announcement">
```

на

```
<class name="com.trade.project.entities.Announcement" table="announcement" 
        schema="trade_project">
```

Красным подчеркнуто то что было и не работало. Зелёным подчеркнута рабочая версия:

[image: скриншот]